# Tkinter font removes button rounding

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.10

I have been messing around with tkinter in the newest version 3.10.4 and have noticed that when you use a special font on a button that it loses the rounding. How do I use a special font while keeping it round?

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
Button(window, text="Example", font=("Courier New bold", 15)).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. I've never seen a case of a font affecting the shape of a button.

Comment: Pretty fascinating! I've never noticed this behavior before now.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah its been bugging me for a while now so I thought I might ask on StackOverflow

Comment: I assumed that was ubuntu.

Comment: @toyotaSupra No. It used to only be on big buttons for mac but in Python3.10.4 it happens on all